# How to remove name with NA in a named list

Tags: r, list

I have the following named list:

```
my_nl <- c(R = 0.0454545454545455, K = 0.204545454545455, `NA's` = 0.75)
```

That looks like this:

```
> my_nl
         R          K       NA's 
0.04545455 0.20454545 0.75000000
```

I want to remove a member of that list with `NA's` as members.
Yielding:

```
         R          K     
0.04545455 0.20454545
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it 'by name', one option is:

```r
my_nl <- c(R = 0.0454545454545455, K = 0.204545454545455, `NA's` = 0.75)
my_nl[names(my_nl) != "NA's"]
#>          R          K 
#> 0.04545455 0.20454545
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using the indexes from the vector, since it is the third element you can either use `-` to remove it or selecting the other values.

```
my_nl <- c(R = 0.0454545454545455, K = 0.204545454545455, `NA's` = 0.75)

#Option 1
my_nl[-3]

#Option 2
my_nl[1:2]
```